# Using Google Indoor Maps to map your home?

Tags: google-maps

I want to be able to track somebody in their own home using their wifi signal on their phones. Is there anyway to do this using Google Indoor Maps? I couldn't find any API currently but I was just asking around just to be sure.

Comment: I don't think that would be possible, because the latitude and longitude can't track that close

Comment: Have you seen http://openlayers.org/ ?  Not sure if it will work, but it is more flexible that google maps api.

Comment: GPS is not accurate enough and Wifi works nothing like GPS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you can track a device by using only one point of reference.

If you use the WIFI signal power, you can only determine the position on the circle with radius set by the dropping in signal strength.

That can't possibly be what you want, you would need to determine the position of the device somewhere on that circle.

But since you only have on point of reference, which is the position of the WIFI emitter (which I'll assume is a wireless router) you cannot.

This is exactly the reason your device needs to "see" (as in direct line of sight) multiple GPS satellites. (it's called triangulation - it's actually a trilateration).

Keep this in mind also: the dropping in signal strength is affected by walls, as well as the angle the wall is forming with the line set by the device and the wifi emitter.

So multiple factors need to be considered when using the wifi signal strenght and converting that to a usable distance.

Hence, you probably won't be able to track somebody indoor using wifi. Unless you set multiple wifi emitters and record their GPS positions, and register their signal strengths in a LOT of points in the house. Which is not really feasible... or is it?

Comment: I see what ur sayin... and it makes perfect sense. Ericsson Labs did something similar: https://labs.ericsson.com/apis/indoor-maps-and-positioning/documentation#Indoor_Positioning_API_for_Android

Answer (score 1):

Assisted GPS, which is what most iPhone and Android devices has, works by detecting Wifi networks and strength nearby and correlating that with GPS signal. If you have neighbors who have wifi that reaches your house, particularly if you multiple neighbors with wifi, it's possible. However, that requires either that a location provider, such as Google or Skyhook or someone else has already registered that overlap and correlated it with location, and that the names of the networks are sufficiently unique (i.e. not everyone has a network named linksys) or that you do the measurements yourself and correlate these points with latitude and longitude.

The best test you can do is actually open up Google Maps on an iPhone or Android device and see if it can track you through the house.